# Tab Control: Partial paint when restoring dialogbox

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013, tabs

The edges of my tab control (SysTabControl32) are not fully repainted after restoring dialog box from minimized state.

Example:

[image]

The control is defined in the resource file (EDIT all occurences of IDD_VJOYCONF):

```
IDD_VJOYCONF DIALOGEX 0, 0, 245, 282
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_3DLOOK | DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_CENTER | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW
CAPTION "vJoyConf - Configure vJoy Devices"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    PUSHBUTTON      "Reset All",IDC_RSTALL,98,261,50,14
    CONTROL         "",IDC_DEVTABS,"SysTabControl32",TCS_MULTILINE | TCS_TOOLTIPS,7,7,231,247
END

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO
BEGIN
    IDD_VJOYCONF, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 238
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 275
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

Developing with VS2013 on Windows 8.

Comment: Does setting the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` style on the dialog help?

Comment: @JonathanPotter Nope.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete dialog template that demonstrates your problem? It doesn't have to be the same one you used in that dialog, just a minimal one that reproduces the issue. Unless that basic one also does. Thanks.

Comment: @andlabs  I added all there is to do with external dialog box IDD_VJOYCONF

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by lifting the margin of the dialog box internal to the tab control.
The more **interesting** thing is how I found the problem.
I used Sysinternals *Process Explorer*. It has a 'Find Window's Process' button:

[image]

[EDIT:]

I hovered over the entire dialog box, highlighting its various elements until I've highlighted the culprit element:

[image]

You can clearly see that it's bottom is clipped exactly where the problem is. This is the dialog box that is embedded in the tab control.

The solution was to raise the dialog box so it won't be clipped.

Comment: Just to make what the cause of the problem was more clear to everyone else, can you show what Process Explorer showed? Thanks.